# What to call a vertex that lies on every maximum matching?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a commonly used name in the literature for vertices in a graph that lie on every maximum matching?

I have seen these vertices appear in several induction proofs, mostly in graph optimization, where they provide a convenient method to separate the inductive step into two separate cases, as the set of graphs that do not contain such a vertex is rather limited. This led me to wonder what other sorts of results relate to these vertices, but it is difficult to search for examples without knowing what they are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is standard notation, but [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=HuDFMwZOwcsC&pg=PA424&lpg=PA424&dq=graph%20theory%20bondy%20murty%20essential%20vertex%20matching&source=bl&ots=xIofvyWVK_&sig=_sHNWzIdJi0JU_5ghWENrRwX3kI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lyBHUYvcJbPg2wXT4IHoCQ&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=graph%20theory%20bondy%20murty%20essential%20vertex%20matching&f=false) (Graph Theory, Bondy and Murty) they use the term *essential*.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I would have upvoted but I don't have enough reputation yet.